# Why defaultValue not working in react-hooks-form with NextUi Select

Tags: reactjs, nextui

```
async function fetchData(id) {
    const userApi = new UserAPI()
    const result = await userApi.getInfoById(id)

    const data: Record<string, any> = result.data
    const other = data.other
    for (const key in other) {
      if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(other, key)) {
        const value = other[key]
        value && (data[key] = value)
      }
    }
    delete data.other

    return data
  }
...
const { register, handleSubmit, control, watch, reset, formState, setValue, getValues } = useForm(
    {
      mode: 'onBlur',
      defaultValues: async () => fetchData(id), 
      // fetchData(id) contained {gender: 0 as number,...} 
    }
  )
...
switch(column.uid)
...
case 'gender':
   return (
     <div className='INPUT'>
        <Select
         classNames={{
           base: ['items-center'],
           label: ['w-[100px]'],
           mainWrapper: ['flex-1'],}}
         isRequired={true}
         label={column.name}
         key={column.uid}
         labelPlacement='outside-left'
         {...register(column.uid, { required: true})}>
            <SelectItem key='0'>man</SelectItem>
            <SelectItem key='1'>male</SelectItem>
         </Select>
    </div>
                        )
```

Why defaultValue not working in react-hooks-form with NextUi Select.

Select UI not show 'man' or 'male' , but empty.

try to add defaultSelectedKeys={getValue('gender')} props.but it get undefined.

Answer (score 1):

This is a `useForm` issue, and can be worked around by 2 options -- `setValue` or `reset`

For `setValue` --

```
const {setValue, ...restOfPropsThatYouNeed} = useForm({...yourData})

useEffect(()=>{
  fetchData(id).then((data)=> setValue(data))
}, [])
```

Or, `reset` (pretty much the same logic as above) --

```
const {reset, ...restOfPropsThatYouNeed} = useForm({...yourData})

useEffect(()=>{
  fetchData(id).then((data)=> reset(data))
}, [])
```